# What does [x] mean, in this context?

Tags: linear-algebra

The question asked
"Find the sum of the solutions to $$x^2+4x+1=[x]$$
I tried solving for the sum claiming that $[x]$ was a scalar matrix, however that was incorrect. I'm not sure what $[x]$ means.

The answer was given to be $-2+\sqrt{2}$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$[x]$, in this context, seems to denote the [Floor Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions). The modern notation is $\lfloor x \rfloor$, but some textbooks still use the archaic notation for the floor function, which is $[x]$ as in the question. Your quadratic can be solved by bounding $x$ using a preexisting bound on the floor function, namely $$x \ge [x] > x-1$$
So this gives us a bound on $x$, which in turn restricts $[x]$. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Basically  you have to solve at first $ x \leq x^2 + 4x + 1 < x+ 1 $

Comment: I think this is incorrect. How is $[x] \ge x$? Try $x=3.5$. $3$ is not greater than $3.5$. What are you saying $[x]$ is?

Comment: I agree with @S.C.B. It should be $x-1<x^2+4x+1\le x$.

Comment: yeah sorry thats  a typo